# Performing fisher exact test on multiple rows of data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
df.t <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6),
                   type=rep(c("A","B"),12),
                   Count.1= rep(c(20,80),12),
                   Count.2=rep(c(70,30),12))
```

and I want to perform fisher test on each row. for example: I want to test  if the count of ID 1 that has 2 types A and B different in count.1 and count.2? I tried different codes at the website but they did not work. Is there any easy function that can do it all the rows grouped by position and type please?
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easier calculation, I would first transform your data structure from a "long" format to "wide". Then set `rownames` to the dataframe, and use `apply()` for the `fisher.test()`. The output is a named list with names come from `rownames` of your dataframe (`ID` in this case).

First two entries of output is pasted here for demonstration.

```
library(tidyverse)

df.t <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6),
                 type=rep(c("A","B"),12),
                 Count.1= rep(c(20,80),12),
                 Count.2=rep(c(70,30),12)) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  pivot_wider(everything(), names_from = type, values_from = c(Count.1, Count.2)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

rownames(df.t) <- df.t[, 1]

df.t <- df.t[, -1]

apply(df.t, 1, function(x) fisher.test(matrix(as.numeric(x[1:4]), ncol=2, byrow=T)))
```

#### List output

```
$`1`

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  matrix(as.numeric(x[1:4]), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
p-value = 1.05e-12
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05288657 0.21489688
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.1086015 


$`2`

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  matrix(as.numeric(x[1:4]), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
p-value = 1.05e-12
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05288657 0.21489688
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.1086015
```

#### p-value output

If you want to simplify your result to only output p-values, you can do:

```
apply(df.t, 1, function(x) fisher.test(matrix(as.numeric(x[1:4]), ncol=2, byrow=T))$p.value)

           1            2            3            4            5 
1.050355e-12 1.050355e-12 1.050355e-12 1.050355e-12 1.050355e-12 
           6 
1.050355e-12
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked perfectly!. one question please, do i need to do a multiple comparison here and how can i adjust the p value in this code?

Comment: If you goal is to compare `Count.1` and `Count.2` of `A` and `B` per `ID`, then I guess this code is already enough. Not sure how do you want to "adjust" your p-value